# BLE communication after pairing

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to BLE.
I understood that pairing is achieved using advertising/scanning schema, based on connection interval.
My question is related to what happens after a connection has been established; is there any periodic message exchange to keep the connection alive? Or the only exchanged data are based on Characteristics' read/write or notification/indication?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: somewhat related: [BLE general questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/122455/7036)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection parameters for a BLE connection is a set of parameters that determine when and how the Central and a Peripheral in a link transmits data. It is always the Central that actually sets the connection parameters used, but the Peripheral can send a so-called Connection Parameter Update Request, that the Central can then accept or reject.

**Connection supervision timeout:** This timeout determines the timeout from the last data exchange till a link is considered lost. A Central will not start trying to reconnect before the timeout has passed, so if you have a device which goes in and out of range often, and you need to notice when that happens, it might make sense to have a short timeout.

for more read this [thread](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/28058/what-is-connection-parameters/110496#110496)